# Comparing two database entries with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I've a table of `Users` with a one-to-many relationship on a table of `Visits` (each `User` had two `Visits`). In `Visits` are multiple columns, including `Score`. For each `User`, I'd like to calculate the difference in their `Score` across the two `Visits`.

What is the most sane way to do this with SQLAlchemy? In lieu of calculating the difference directly in the database call, I'd be fine with pulling the `Score` for each `Visit`, assuming they're already matched together via having the same User. Then it's just `Score1-Score2`.

Note: It's straightforward to pull all the `Score` and `Users` where `Visits.visit_number==1`, then again where `Visits.visit_number==2`.

```
data = session.query(Visit.Score, User.id).join(User).filter(Visits.visit_number==1)
data2 = session.query(Visit.Score, User.id).join(User).filter(Visits.visit_number==2)
```

The problem is matching up the two sets of scores is a major pain (as they will not be in order by user, and there may be users who haven't yet had a second visit). I'm sure there's an elegant way to do it in SQLAlchemy, probably with aliases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will return the list of `(User.id, Score1-Score2)` pairs for users that have (at least) 2 visits:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased

Visit1 = aliased(Visit)
Visit2 = aliased(Visit)
session.query(User)\
    .join(Visit1, (Visit1.user_id==User.id) & (Visit1.visit_number==1))\
    .join(Visit2, (Visit2.user_id==User.id) & (Visit2.visit_number==2))\
    .values(User.id, Visit1.Score-Visit2.Score)
```

Here `Visit.user_id` is a column referring to `User.id`.

In fact it's safe to exclude the table for `User` from join chain, since `Visit`'s table already has `User`'s id and you don't request other data from its table.